# Finding matching value from one attribute to another using jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes

OK in this example I have a variable that will help me load some ajax.

```
var postname = itsname;
```

I need to be able to find the matching value from attribute data-postname and obtain the value of data-slider using jQuery. So with this example I need to obtain 2 in order to load the right slide.

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <a data-slider="0" data-postname="somename" href="#"></a>
    <a data-slider="1" data-postname="anothername" href="#"></a>
    <a data-slider="2" data-postname="itsname" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Many thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var postname = "itsname",
    slider = $("#mydiv a[data-postname='" + postname + "']").data("slider");

console.log(slider);  // "2"
```

Comment: @VisioN +1 How is it that data becomes a function and slider a parameter?

Comment: @Barmar `jQuery.data` is a bit different thing: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/.